# Scroller without scrollY

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Is it possible to use scroller datatables plugin without specified scrollY?

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '/besom/entity/websearch/list/ajax',
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'query' },
        { data: 'resultLimit' },
        { data: 'created' },
        { data: 'success' },
        { data: 'performed' } ],
//      language: { "loadingRecords": "loading data..." },
    scrollY: 400,
    lengthChange: false,
    deferRender: true,
    scroller: {
//  loadingIndicator: true,
//  displayBuffer: 20
    },
//  scrollCollapse: true
})
```

If I comment out scrollY "this.dom.scroller is undefined" error occurs. Is it correct behavior of datatables? My example data is:

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":184227,"recordsFiltered":184227,"data": [
{"id":4,"resultLimit":100,"query":" ","site":"facebook.com","startIndex":91,"success":true,"created":1428769822000,"performed":1433538000000},
{"id":5,"resultLimit":100,"query":"product","site":"facebook.com","startIndex":91,"success":true,"created":1428769822000,"performed":1433538000000}],
"error":null}
```

Is it another way or workaround to allow infinite scroll via main browser scrollbar?

Comment: Using main scrollbar, probably not possible with `scroller` as it always uses the tables won scrollbar. You can set the height of the table to match the viewport with `scrollY: '100vh'` if that helps.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with a combination of DataTables and [jQuery.Lazy()](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/). Place something in the last row of the table, and when Lazy triggers it's visible, load more data into the table.